# Sudo command working on unix but not from java code

Tags: java, unix, sudo, processbuilder

I am running below unix sudo command and its working perfectly there.
    *sudo -u xfbcft -i*
Issue is that when I try the same why java process builder stuff, I am getting permission denied exception on Unix.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("Going to execute:");
    runUnixComand();
}

private static void runUnixComand() {
    Process p;
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        String [] cmdArray ={"sudo -u xfbcft -i ","cftping -v","exit"};

        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdArray);
        builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
        //builder.redirectOutput();
        Process process = builder.start();
        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("op:"+line);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Below is the exception line I am getting on Unix terminal.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo -u xfbcft -i ": error=13, Permission denied
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "sudo -u xfbcft -i ": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at JdbcTest.runUnixComand(JdbcTest.java:23)
        at JdbcTest.main(JdbcTest.java:8)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Note : I have entries in sudoers file and individual commands are running fine on unix. Also, user running this java program and individual command is same. Please Guide.

Comment: Does your user have `NOPASSWD` set?

Comment: sudo can't prompt you for the password if you don't pipe stdin. Though consider running the java program as sudo instead.

Comment: Sudo actually will refuse to accept a password over stdin (it interacts with /dev/tty directly). You can fake it out with a pty, but using NOPASSWD is probably a much better solution. Also, don't use `sudo -i` if you're not running interactively! Instead you want to just execute `sudo -u xfbcft cftping -v` as a single command.

Comment: There might be something more fundamental going on here: it looks like you're getting a permission denied error directly from `forkAndExec`. Maybe you need to use the full path to the `sudo` executable?

Comment: yes, I have set NOPASSWD and its working from machine

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code as below and it works like charm.

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/sh", "-c", "sudo -H -u xfbcft -i");
            builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

so matter was to execute it from bin/sh